# Why does it keep returning 1 when trying to get the sum of n natural numbers?

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

I have tried to create a program to get the sum of n natural numbers using a while loop specifically but it keeps returning 1 instead of 15, I am not sure where I went wrong. If anyone has any idea I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
def summation(n):
    ttl = 0
    while n != 1:
        ttl = ttl + n
        n = n - 1
    return 1

print(summation(5))
```

Comment: It returns `1` because you wrote `return 1`?

Comment: Try `return ttl`

Comment: I removed return one but then it doesn't output anything, do you know how I can make output the sum of the first 5 natural numbers?

Comment: Note that this can be more succinctly written as `def summation(n): return sum(range(n + 1))`.

Comment: Your sum doesn't add 1. So `summation(5)` will be `5 + 4 + 3 + 2`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Try returning `ttl` (you might want to consider renaming `ttl` to `total` the two extra characters increase readability a lot), and including the last `1`:

```
--- before/before.py
+++ after/after.py
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
def summation(n):
     ttl = 0
-    while n != 1:
+    while n >= 1:
         ttl = ttl + n
         n = n - 1
-    return 1
+    return ttl

print(summation(5))
```

**Output:**

```
15
```